# How to Disable link preview in telegraf

Tags: telegram, telegraf, telegraf.js

I can not find in the docs how to disable the annoying link preview. Anyone knows how to?

```
const { Extra} = require('telegraf')
bot.reply('Hello http://github.com', Extra.webPreview(false))
```

I have tried above code but showing Extra as Undefined.
Also how to disable link preview using **ctx.replyWithHTML()** method ?

Answer (score 3):

I am hoping that you are using Telegraf V4 or later.

`Extra` isn't available in Telegraf V4.

```js
bot.replyWithHTML(`Your Message`, { 
    disable_web_page_preview: true 
})
```

Also the difference between `reply` & `replyWithHTML` is with `replyWithHTML` enables the `parse_mode` as HTML